# Get all image in media Gallery with alt/title?

Tags: plugins, images, attachments, attachment-fields-to-edit

Is there a way to fetch the **ALT/TITLE**  of ALL images in the media gallery?

I think this would be an easy way for a website to have a Pictures page that just pulls all of the images from the media gallery, granted it would only be necessary in certain scenarios.

I don't need instructions on how to create a Pictures page, just how to pull all of the image URLs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

/*
* Template Name: Gallery Page
*/

$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

?>
<?php get_header();?>
<div class="main">
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID,'thumbnail' );?>
            </div>
        <?php }?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: it's work thank you... can you answer my other question?

Comment: please.... can you answer question this  [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/393030/how-to-get-all-attachment-image-from-post-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID,'thumbnail' );
}
```

Comment: how to use this code? can you please tell me

Comment: Create a page with your custom template and put this code in your template file

Comment: Please check new posted code