# How to get all attachment image from post ?? WordPress

Tags: plugins, attachments, gallery, attachment-fields-to-edit

I just want to get all atachment image from post with **Alt, description, title, size, resotution**

and how to add DOWNLOAD button?

i want to create image downloading website on wordpress for example [LINK](https://wallpaperboat.com/the-last-of-us-iphone-wallpapers)

```
 <?php  $args = array(
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'numberposts'    => -1, // show all
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
            'order'           => 'ASC'
       );

$images = get_posts($args);
if($images) { ?>
<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
  <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID); ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*
* Template Name: Gallery Page
*/

$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

?>
<?php get_header();?>
<div class="main">
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID); ?>" >
<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID); ?>" download>Download</a>
            </div>
        <?php }?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: how to get only post attachment images?

Comment: get attachment images only who attach to post

Comment: You can check with post_parent with the current loop. If you get post parent id then you can get post using post parent id